# Trouble with AngularJS $filter('number'), Deletes number after 3 characters

Tags: angularjs, input, filter, numbers

I have an input that requires the entry to be only numbers (I know there is an `input type="number"` but I don't like the spinner that gets put on it), so I thought I would use AngularJS's $filter('number') and watch the variable on the `$scope` for changes and filter it accordingly.  It works fine but when someone inputs a number over 1000, it deletes the entire number and starts over again.

Here's a fiddle that demostrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/xxAq2/

Comment: I used this in my code instead of the $filter: `$scope.num = $scope.num.replace(/[^0-9]/,'');` just wondering why it happens in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the return value of `$filter('number')("1000")` is "1,000" and not "1000", then parseInt returns only whatever comes before the ','.

Change your code to this:

```
parseInt($filter('number')("1000").replace(/,/g, ""))
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxAq2/6/)

Edit: In the fiddle you put in the comment (without parseInt) , it still fails because of the following series of events:

1) 100 is changed to 1000, your watch callback jumps, and changes 1000 to 1,000.

2) 1000 is changed to 1,000, so the callback jumps again, but then changes 1,000 to "" because $filter('number')("1,000") returns ""

3) 1,000 changes to "" , resulting in the empty textbox that you see.

Comment: I did it without using parseInt as well and still the same result: http://jsfiddle.net/xxAq2/2/

Comment: I edited - I posted a working jsfiddle to my solution + answered why your jsfiddle version 2 does not work

Comment: I did come to the conclusion that the `$watch` was being called twice once on user input and then again because `$filter` added in the comma.  Still not sure why you can't input a number in the millions in your fiddle though? Look at my second comment - if you type in 123456 and then try and type 7 you'll never get there.

Comment: I fixed the code so 9,999,999 will work ('.replace' only replaces the first occurrence of ','). By the way you can just use "isNaN" :)

Comment: ah the Perl global switch, forgot about that.